# How do you calculate the error propagation in a Helmholtz coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, error-analysis

I'm having some trouble with the error propagation expression in a Helmholtz-coil.
Specifically $\frac{\frac{∂B}{∂R}}{B}$.
If anyone could help, I'd be really grateful.

The formula used is
$$B(x) = \frac{NMI}{2R} \cdot \left(
\left(1+\left(\frac{x+\frac{a}{2}}{R}\right)^2\right)^{-3/2}
+\left(1+\left(\frac{x-\frac{a}{2}}{R}\right)^2\right)^{-3/2}
\right)$$

$N$ = Number of wire coils

$M$ = Magnetic constant

$R$ = Radius of coil

$x$ = Distance from mid-point of coils

$a$ = Distance between coils (in this case $2R$, $R$, and $R/2$)

$I$ = Electric current

Comment: I can cheat and suggest a symbolic math application such as Mathematica or Maple. What you will obtain is undoubted a mess to simplify. Since the mathematics to answer your question directly is "straight-forward" by today's standards of tools, what is your true intent with this question?

Comment: I've been having great trouble solving it, and almost cracked under the stress. Therefore I decided to ask here.

Comment: When I would have to do this by hand, I'd be under stress too. But, I am also no longer having to write only on clay tablets or use an abacus to multiple two irrational numbers. So ... cheat and then work the answer backward by hand as needed. Finally, given your reply, I suggest this question is better posted for math exchange rather than here.

Comment: @DapperDude Do you want to give a hit with the formulas I typed?

Comment: @KV18 I'm sorry, I'm new on this site, so what is a hit (also english is not my first language)

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Oh, ok, I apologize for posting at the wrong forum.

Comment: No I meant if you tried using the formulas that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: The error propogation can be calculated for a relation $Z\pm\Delta Z=(A\pm\Delta A)^n(B\pm\Delta B)^m$ , and $Z\pm\Delta Z=\frac{(A\pm\Delta A)^n}{(B\pm\Delta B)^m}$

$$\frac{\Delta Z}{Z}=n\frac{\Delta A}{A} +m\frac{\Delta B}{B}$$

The propogation for $Z\pm\Delta Z=(A\pm\Delta A)(B\pm\Delta B)$ is:
$$\Delta Z=\Delta A+\Delta B$$

Only quantities that have some *error* in them should be substituted into this propogation.

Comment: As I would understand, this is a first order estimate of the maximum error. It is not the approach required by linear propagation.

Comment: Probably. This error analysis only works assuming the product of the uncertainites (eg. $\Delta A * \Delta B$) to be negligible.

Comment: The physical statement is to recognize that the errors are uncorrelated. The formula for linear propagation also make this assumption but uses expansions in second derivatives not first derivatives. Also, the OP is only asking about the derivative with respect to one term and not the expansion with respect to all terms.